# User Array length and value in on place

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have an array that I need to repeat the fields based on its length and also use one of the array field to name the fields. How should I do this?
My sample code is here. Please take a look at it   [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5nskq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Detail**

```
  detail:any[]=[
{id:1,value:'RAM',subcatid:1},
{id:2,value:'LCD',subcatid:1},
{id:3,value:'CPU',subcatid:1},
{id:4,value:'GPU',subcatid:1},
{id:5,value:'Camera',subcatid:1},
{id:1,value:'TRAM',subcatid:2},
{id:2,value:'TLCD',subcatid:2},
{id:3,value:'TCPU',subcatid:2},
{id:4,value:'TGPU',subcatid:2},
{id:5,value:'TCamera',subcatid:2}
 ]
```

Fields are created correctly, but I do not know the names of the fields. How should I display. The value of the fields should also be presented and displayed. How should I do this?

this Real Code :

**TS :**

```
    addProductFG:FormGroup;
  cats:Category[];
  subCats:Category[];
  PD:Productdetail[];
  selectedCat:number;
  valueIngrident=new FormArray([]);
  public loading=false;
  public progress: number=0;
  public messsage:string;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient,private fb:FormBuilder,private productService:ProductinfoService,private catService:CategoryService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading=true;
    this.InitialFrom();
    this.GetMainCat();
  }

  public CreateValueFiled(PD:Productdetail[]){
      PD.map(element => {
        this.valueIngrident.push(
          new FormGroup({
            infoId:new FormControl(element.id),
            value:new FormControl('')
          })
        )
      });
  }

  public GetMainCat(){
    this.catService.GetMainCat().subscribe(
      res=>{
        this.cats=res;
        this.loading=false;
      }
    )
  }

  get ValueFormControl(){
      return  this.addProductFG.get('values') as FormArray;
  }

  public InitialFrom():FormGroup{

    this.addProductFG=this.fb.group({
      productTitle:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      productName:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      color:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      productImageName:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      price:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      gurantyMonth:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      gurantyCompanyName:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      values:this.valueIngrident
    })
    return this.addProductFG;
  }
  public ChangeSubCat(id:number){
    this.loading=true;
      this.catService.GetSubCatByCatId(id).subscribe(
          res=>{
            this.subCats=res;
            this.loading=false;
          }
        )
  }

  public ChangeFormByType(id:number){
    this.loading=true;
      this.productService.GetPCIBySubId(id).subscribe(
        res=>{
          this.PD=res,
          this.CreateValueFiled(this.PD),
          this.loading=false;
        }
      )
  }
```

and **HTML** Code :

```
    <div class="form-inline lbin" formArrayName="values">
                <div class="form-inline lbin" *ngFor="let valueCtrl of ValueFormControl.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <div  class="form-inline lbin">
                        <label>{{PD.infoNames[i].infoName}}</label> 
                        <input formControlName="value" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is ProductDetail :

```
export interface Productdetail {
id:number;
catId:number;
infoNames:Detail[];
}
```

and this **Detail :**

```
export interface Detail {
infoName:string;
}
```

Comment: @Mukyuu i put that

Comment: You want to bind only value to form controls or label also?

Comment: @RakeshMakluri i need use in label

Comment: What do you want to show as label and as input value?

Comment: @RakeshMakluri i want to fill label to each input

Comment: @RakeshMakluri For example, instead of `g` using RAM, CPU, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You has type error, must be

```
<!--is "AddP", not addP-->
<form *ngIf="AddP" [formGroup]="AddP">
  <!--is "values" not valueIng, is formArrayName, not formArray-->
  <div formArrayName="values">
    <div *ngFor="let valueCtrl of ValueFormControl.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div  class="form-inline lbin">
          <!--I supouse you wwant to do some like this-->
          <label>{{detail[i].value}}</label>
          <input formControlName="value" >
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
{{AddP?.value|json}}
```

Therefore in ngOnInit, you must call befor to CreateValueField

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.CrateValueFiled();
    this.InitForm();
  }
```

Well, An idea to improve your code. Why your function CreateValueFiled not return a formArray, like

```
  public CrateValueFiled(detail) {
    let controls: FormGroup[] = [];
    detail.forEach(el => {
      controls.push(
        new FormGroup({
          id: new FormControl(el.id),
          value: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required]))
        })
      )
    })
    return new FormArray(controls)
  }
```

Then your NgInit becomes

```
public InitForm(): FormGroup {
    this.AddP = this.fb.group({
      values: this.CrateValueFiled(this.detail)
    });
    // return this.AddP; <--you need'nt return this.AddP
  }
```

see [your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gs8ye?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

NOTE: Try use camel-case notation

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over form array controls, iterate over data.

Forked and updated the solution [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9w9f6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

component html

```
<form [formGroup]="AddP" >
  <div formArrayName="values">
    <div *ngFor="let d of detail; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div  class="form-inline lbin">
          <label> {{d.value}}</label>
          <input formControlName="value" >
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```